# Deleting user from Admin API does not trigger .onAuthStateChanged in client

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am deleting a user from a firebase cloud function.

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(user_uid)
```

However, I was expecting that the following **client side listener** would trigger:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => // do stuff)
```

That is to say, the users deletion would also change his/her auth state from `signedIn` to `signedOut`.

The cloud-function call executes correctly, however the user is still logged in. Do I also have to log them out? (I see no admin `.logOut` method available.

I was thinking that after the successful Function execution I would then programmatically log them out from the client side.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Deleting the user from the client side does trigger `.onAuthStateChanged`, so from the **client side** it does change his/ her auth state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way auth state listeners work on the client.  Those listeners trigger when the state changes from the perspective of the client.  It doesn't know of changes that happen immediately on the server, at least not until the client tries to refresh its auth token.  It's not "realtime" in connection with the server like Realtime Database.

If you want to wire up your own client notifications for user deletion, you could have the client listen to a per-user location in Realtime Database, and use the changes there to know when the user has been deleted.